# Select blocks of lines between $blockBEGIN and $blockEND containing specific pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to select blocks containing a specific regexp pattern inspired from [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/668915/135038) :

```bash
$ blockBEGIN='ID'
$ blockEND='Sector Size'
$ myPATTERN='Ready'
$ cat pdisks-simplified-20230825.log | sed -n "/$blockBEGIN/,/$blockEND/{/$blockEND/"'s/$/\x00/;p}' | grep -z "$myPATTERN" | grep -z -v "$blockEND" | tr -d '\x00'
$
```

But nothing shows up.

Sample input:

```
ID                              : 0:1:4
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Ready
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Capacity                        : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : ST4000NM0023
Serial No.                      : Z1Z6AAR9
Part Number                     : TH0529FG212334AI01AGA02
Sector Size                     : 512B
ID                              : 0:1:0
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Not Applicable
Bus Protocol                    : SATA
Media                           : SSD
Capacity                        : 372.00 GB (399431958528 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : INTEL SSDSC2BX400G4R
Serial No.                      : BTHC721403F8400VGN
Part Number                     : CN065WJJIT200766014OA00
Sector Size                     : 512B
```

Here is a matching block from the `pdisks-simplified-20230825.log` file that looks like this :

```
ID                              : 0:1:4
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Ready
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Capacity                        : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : ST4000NM0023
Serial No.                      : Z1Z6AAR9
Part Number                     : TH0529FG212334AI01AGA02
Sector Size                     : 512B
$
```

And here is a non matching block from the `pdisks-simplified-20230825.log` file that looks like this :

```
ID                              : 0:1:0
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Online
Power Status                    : Not Applicable
Bus Protocol                    : SATA
Media                           : SSD
Capacity                        : 372.00 GB (399431958528 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : INTEL SSDSC2BX400G4R
Serial No.                      : BTHC721403F8400VGN
Part Number                     : CN065WJJIT200766014OA00
Sector Size                     : 512B
$
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: please update the question with a couple sample blocks - one that matches the desired pattern, one that does not match the desired pattern (right now your pattern - `Ready` - does not show up in the sample data so it's hard to tell if your code has a technical/logic issue or if you're not getting any output because there really is no match ... ???); also update the question with the desired output

Comment: @markp-fuso Just added a matching block and a non matching block.

Comment: @Fravadona I'm not selecting lines but blocks between `$blockBEGIN` and `$blockEND` with a line containing `$myPATTERN` each.

Comment: BTW, what command generates this output? it looks like SAS3IRCU but it's a little different

Comment: @Fravadona My `pdisks-simplified-20230825.log` file is generated by `omreport storage pdisk controller=0 | egrep '^(ID|Status|Capacity|Sector Size|Bus|Power|Media|State|Vendor|Product|Serial|Part.Number|^$)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- blocks are separated by a blank line (as in OP's original question)
- all blocks start with `ID` and end with `Sector Size` (otherwise we'll need to add some more logic)

If `awk` is an acceptable solution:

```
awk -v myptn="${myPATTERN}" 'BEGIN {RS=""} $0 ~ myptn' block.log
```

Where:

- `-v myptn="${myPATTERN}"` - populate the `awk` variable named `myptn` with the bash/OS variable's value
- `RS=""` - define record separator as blank line
- `$0 ~ myptn` - if the record contains the string/pattern contained in the `awk` variable named `myptn` then print the record [**NOTE:** this will match on any string within the block so if OP needs to be more specific then we'll need to expand the code]
- `block.log` contains both sample blocks provided by OP

When `myPATTERN="Ready"` this generates:

```
ID                              : 0:1:4
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Ready
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Capacity                        : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : ST4000NM0023
Serial No.                      : Z1Z6AAR9
Part Number                     : TH0529FG212334AI01AGA02
Sector Size                     : 512B
```

---

Another approach based on strings that delimit the start/end of a block:

```
awk -v bstart="${blockBEGIN}" -v bend="${blockEND}" -v myptn="${myPATTERN}" '

index($0,bstart)==1 { inblock = 1 }                              # if line starts with "bstart" then enable flag
index($0,bend)==1   { if (block ~ myptn)                         # if line starts with "bend" then ...
                         print block                             # print current block and ...
                      block=""                                   # reset our
                      inblock=0                                  # varables
                    }

inblock             { block = block (block ? ORS : "" ) $0 }     # if flag is set then append current line to variable "block"
' block.log
```

**NOTES:**

- assumes `bstart` and `bend` start in the 1st character of the line otherwise replace the `index()` calls with an appropriate to match `bstart` and `bend`
- assumes `bstart` and `bend` are unique enough to only match one row in a block

This generates:

```
ID                              : 0:1:4
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Ready
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Capacity                        : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : ST4000NM0023
Serial No.                      : Z1Z6AAR9
Part Number                     : TH0529FG212334AI01AGA02
```

Comment: Just for a more general use-case, if there were no blank lines separating the blocks, how would that have changed your `awk` command ?

Comment: @SebMa added a 2nd answer based on starting/ending strings

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your "blocks" are "empty-line" delimited so it's quite easy to use `awk` for filtering them out:

```bash
awk -F'\n' -v RS='' '$1 ~ /^ID/ && $NF ~ /^Sector Size/ && /: Ready/' pdisks-simplified-20230825.log
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `\>` word boundaries, this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -v beg="$blockBEGIN" -v mid="$myPATTERN" -v end="$blockEND"  '
    BEGIN { RS = "\n" end "\\>[^\n]*" }
    sub("(^|.*\n)"beg"\\>",beg) && ($0~mid) { print $0 RT }
' file
ID                              : 0:1:4
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Ready
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Capacity                        : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : ST4000NM0023
Serial No.                      : Z1Z6AAR9
Part Number                     : TH0529FG212334AI01AGA02
Sector Size                     : 512B
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl might be better suited for this use case, which does not need blank lines as separator :

```
perl -0777 -ne '
  $blockBEGIN="ID";
  $blockEND="Sector Size";
  $myPATTERN="Ready";
  while (/^$blockBEGIN.*?$blockEND[^\n]+/gms) {
    $block=$&;
    print "$block\n" if ($block =~ /$myPATTERN/);
  }
' input.file
```

`-0777` puts perl into slurp mode so it reads the whole file.

As for `/PATTERN/gms`:

`g` : globally match the pattern repeatedly in the string

`m` : Treat the string being matched against as multiple lines. That is, change "^" and "$" from matching the start of the string's first line and the end of its last line to matching the start and end of each line within the string.

`s` : Treat the string as single line. That is, change "." to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

`$&` The string matched by the last successful pattern match.

Comment: I love small code solutions :) BTW : Can you please add a little explanation for `perl -0777` and for `/PATTERN/gms` ?

Comment: @SebMa This script catches the essence of your requirements, making it more readable.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing : can you add a little description of the `$&` variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no line break between blocks, you can break the file into blocks based on a regex then parse that into key/value pairs.

Ruby or Perl with be the best to do that.

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -e '$<.read.split(/^(?<!\A)(?=ID\s)/).each{|blk|
    kv=blk.split(/\R/).map{|line| line.split(/\s+:\s+/)}.to_h
    puts blk if kv["State"]=="Ready" 
}' file
```

Or you can use a block approach with any awk:

```
awk '
BEGIN{cnt=0}
{blk[cnt]=blk[cnt] ? blk[cnt] ORS $0 : $0}
    FNR>1 && /^ID /{cnt++}
END{for(i=0; i<=cnt; i++) 
    if (blk[i]~/State[[:space:]]+:[[:space:]]+Ready/) print blk[i]}
' file
```

Or,

```
awk '
/^ID[[:space:]]/ {
    if (s~/State[[:space:]]+:[[:space:]]+Ready/) print s 
    s=$0 ORS
    next
}    
{s=s $0 ORS}
' file
```

Either prints the matching block:

```
ID                              : 0:1:4
Status                          : Ok
State                           : Ready
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Capacity                        : 3,725.50 GB (4000225165312 bytes)
Vendor ID                       : DELL(tm)
Product ID                      : ST4000NM0023
Serial No.                      : Z1Z6AAR9
Part Number                     : TH0529FG212334AI01AGA02
Sector Size                     : 512B
```